# ListView: How to go to a new activity on clicking a button in the ListView?

Tags: android

I have a ListView on MainActivity and each item contains a textView and a button.

I want to go to an Activity(say X) on clicking the button in the list.
So my first thought was to setOnClickListener for the button in my custom adapter and use intent to go to activity X.
I wrote this inside `setOnClickListener` of button in the custom adapter:

`Intent intent = new Intent(MainAcivity.this, ActivityX.class);`

I can not pass `MainActivity.this` as the first parameter for the intent as it is not the enclosing class.

What can I do?

My goal is to go from `MainActivity` to `ActivityX` on clicking the button inside of a `ListView`.

Comment: Pass reference of the activity in the constructor of adapter. Then you can launch into new `Activity`. 
`Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityX.class);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `Context`. You can get the context from a `Activity`, from a `Fragment` or from a `View`.

Method `onClick(View view)` gives to you a reference of the view which was clicked. So, you can get the context from that view.

For example:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View viewClicked) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(viewClicked.getContext(), ActivityX.class);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list.setAdapter(adapter);list.setOnItemClickListener(new     AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, Viewview,int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainAcivity.this, ActivityX.class);
                            }
                        });
```

or you can call by position

```
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, Viewview,int position, long id) 
{if (position ==0){ 
Intent intent = new Intent(MainAcivity.this, ActivityX.class);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following approach.

1. Create a class that implements `ListAdapter`. (or just subclass `ArrayAdapter`), the Adapter that backs your list.
2. Define an interface in that class that contains a callback that passes an identifier for the button that was clicked. 
   Example:

```
         public interface ListButtonClickListener{
                void onListButtonClicked(<some identifier for the button that was clicked);
            }
```

3. Create a member variable of type `ListButtonClickListener` in the `ListAdapter`subclass created in step 1.
4. In your `Activity`, create an anonymous class implementing the `ListButtonClickListener`. The `onListButtonClicked()` method will handle the specific button that was clicked using the identifier and is where you will start the `Activity` from.
5. Set the instance of the `ListButtonClickListener` created in step 4 as the member variable in step 3.
6. In the `Button` `OnClickListener`'s in your `Adapter` subclass, invoke the  `onListButtonClicked()` callback with that button's unique identifier.  The `ListButtonClickListener` implementation defined in step 4 will then handle the `Activity` launch.